# Num of download option in contentversion query

Tags: query

Querying Top contents:

```
select id, Title, Description, FileType,FeaturedContentDate,FeaturedContentBoost, Owner.Name, VersionNumber, ContentDocumentId,TagCsv from ContentVersion where FeaturedContentDate=null and FeaturedContentBoost=null Order By CreatedDate Desc LIMIT 10
```

I need to get  top contents by number of downloads. Number of download option is available in content version history.

How can I include the download option in my content version query?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me:

```
 ID cvid;
 for (AggregateResult ar: [SELECT ContentVersionId cvid, Count(ID) total FROM 
     ContentVersionHistory WHERE Field = 'contentVersionDownloaded'
GROUP BY ContentVersionId ORDER BY Count(ID) DESC LIMIT 10
  ]) {

    cvid = String.valueOf(ar.get('cvid'));
}

for (ContentVersion content: [select id, Title, Description, FileType, 
    FeaturedContentDate, FeaturedContentBoost, Owner.Name, VersionNumber, 
ContentDocumentId, TagCsv from ContentVersion
where ID IN: totalset 
 Order By CreatedDate Desc LIMIT 10
  ]) {
  contentList.add(content);
 }
```